# How to Create H1 to H6 Headings using Sass to CSS with decreased font size

Tags: css, loops, sass

I would like to create H1 to H6 heading tags using SASS. My requirement is the CSS should be start from H1 and its font size should be 3.5rem which needs to be reduced by 0.5rem in each Headings.

The required CSS code should be as follows:

```
h1 {font-size:3.5rem;}
h2 {font-size:3rem;}
h3 {font-size:2.5rem;}
h4 {font-size:2rem;}
h5 {font-size:1.5rem;}
h6 {font-size:1rem;}
```

I tried the following SASS:

```
$size: 3.5rem;

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: $size - $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: ' size -$1' is obviously wrong. You only want to reduce the value by 0.5 per loop

Comment: I found this working `font-size: $size - $i / 2`

Comment: @Mahdi Thank You for Your Suggestion. Its actually Working, but I got a more descriptive code from hypax So i am voting for him. Sorry for that  but I put your code is to a usefull answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to subtract the .5rem from the font size each time, not $i.

```scss
$size: 3.5rem;

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: $size - 0.5rem * ($i - 1);
  }
}
```

That provided me with the following CSS:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hypax, This is amazing and this is what I was looking for. Its Brilliant. Thank You Very Much for Instant Support. Let me also know how the H1 start from exactly 3.5rem even if you make some calculation in the first iteration. I am curious to know about it.

Comment: Well, I am using `$i - 1` so for h1 it actually is `$size - 0.5rem * 0`. So, the number of the corresponding heading is always reduced by 1. That's why the h1 doesn't get reduced by 0.5.